# Change rasters' z value to minus (Below sealeave)

Tags: raster, dem, arcgis-pro, raster-calculator, reclassify

My current raster has positive values for all features but I need them all to be negative as it is for a seafloor basin. A handful of values are negative but most are positive. I have access to ArcGIS Pro.

Comment: When you say a handful of values are negative, are these correctly negative? Are the other values the correct number, just positive when they should be negative? Please edit your question to add more details about what you have, what you've tried, and where you are getting stuck.

Comment: yes, they all need to be negative. But only some of the values in the original data have the negative value. All of them need to have it as the surface is below sea level

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [Conditional tool](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/con-.htm) (either by itself or within Raster Calculator) to say "If value > 0 then multiply by -1; otherwise leave the original value alone". It should look something like this:

Con(raster > 0, raster*-1, raster)

Comment: Thank you very much; this was simple and worked! i appreciate your help

Comment: Great! When you find an answer that works the best thing to do is accept it (click the check mark on the left side of the answer, just below the voting arrows). This marks that a solution has been found, and removes it from the Unanswered Questions list.